# How to make PREPARE TRANSACTION work

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

As per Postgres Documentation - Once prepared, a transaction can later be committed or rolled back with COMMIT PREPARED or ROLLBACK PREPARED, respectively. Those commands can be issued from any session, `not only the one that executed the original transaction.`

I am trying to import data from csv into database tables and for this, I am using the

`COPY tablename [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' }`

all this is done in a shell script.
Now the issue is that I am executing `psql` command and passing this command as parameter via the `-c` option ( I start transaction via the command

`prepare transaction 'some-id'` in that command).

I want to create a Savepoint and rollback to it incase of any errors.

After a few other tasks in the shell script, I check for errors that the previous psql statement have produced and when I then try to rollback using the command

`Prepared Rollback 'transaction-id'` ( in separate `psql command with sql statements` )

It reports "`No "transaction-id" found`"

Am I getting the concept wrong or missing something in the process?

Is this happening because I am issuing `psql` command multiple time and each is resulting in new transaction ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your prepare to work, the `COPY` and `PREPARE` must be in the same session. Since your question lacks concrete commands, I'm assuming that when you write:

> Prepared Rollback 'transaction-id' ( in separate psql command with sql statements )

You're using different psql commands to COPY and PREPARE. This is wrong. Combine the COPY and PREPARE to the same session.

E.g.

```
$ psql -c "BEGIN; COPY tablename FROM '/tmp/sql'; PREPARE TRANSACTION 'foobar';" db
$ while /bin/not-ready-to-commit ; do sleep 1 ; done
$ psql -c "COMMIT PREPARED 'foobar';" db
```

The `PREPARE TRANSACTION` works by writing the current transaction to the disc and exiting the transaction process in the current session. This is why you need a `BEGIN`: it starts the transaction you want to prepare. All commands you want to be affected by the prepeare must come after the transaction has been started (in your case the COPY command). When the `PREPARE TRANSACTION` is issued, the transaction you are currently in is written to disk with the identifier you give. Any statements issued after the transaction is prepared are no   longer part of the transaction. So doing `BEGIN; PREPARE... ; COPY` runs the COPY operation without a transaction.

Here's an example in psql shell:

```
demo=# DELETE FROM foo;
DELETE 4
demo=# BEGIN; -- start a transaction
BEGIN
DEMO=# COPY foo FROM '/tmp/sql'; -- do what you want to commit later
COPY 4
demo=# PREPARE TRANSACTION 'demo'; -- prepare the transaction
PREPARE TRANSACTION
demo=# ROLLBACK; -- this is just to show that there is no longer a transaction
NOTICE:  there is no transaction in progress
ROLLBACK
demo=# SELECT * FROM foo; -- the table is empty, copy waiting for commit
 a | b 
---+---
(0 rows)
demo=# COMMIT PREPARED 'demo'; -- do the commit
COMMIT PREPARED
demo=# SELECT * FROM foo; -- data is visible
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
 5 | 6
 7 | 8
(4 rows)
```

**Edit:** You must enable prepared transactions in postgresql.conf:

```
max_prepared_transactions = 1 # or more, zero (default) disables this feature.
```

If `max_prepared_transactions` is zero, psql reports that the transaction id is not found, but does not warn you about this feature being disabled. Psql gives a warning for `PREPARE TRANSACTION` but it's easy to miss if your shell scripts print stuff after the prepare statement.

Answer (score 5):

`PREPARE TRANSACTION` is for **distributed** transactions across *multiple* servers, usually used by transaction monitors or similar application servers (e.g. EJB).

Simply wrap your copy in a regular transaction block:

```
START TRANSACTION;
COPY ....;
COMMIT;
```

If you want a savepoint in the middle, use `SAVEPOINT some_name` and then you can rollback to that savepoint.